# In RouteAction.php line 84: Invalid route action

Tags: laravel

When I create a controller in laravel 5.4 I get this error

> In RouteAction.php line 84:
>
> Invalid route action:
>   [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController].

I do not create Admin/DashboardController. Still makes a errors

web.php

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => ['auth:web', 'CheckAdmin'], 'prefix' => 'admin'],function (){
    $this->resource('authorities', 'AuthoritiesController');
    $this->resource('complaints', 'ComplaintsController');
    $this->resource('schools-list', 'SchoolsListController');
    $this->resource('inspection-failed', 'InspectionFailedController');
    $this->resource('inspection-register', 'InspectionRegisterController');
    $this->resource('inspection-results', 'InspectionResultsController');
    $this->resource('inspectors-list', 'InspectionListController');
    $this->resource('investigators', 'InvestigatorsController');
    $this->resource('notification-infringement', 'NotificationInfringementController');
    $this->resource('system-experts', 'SystemExpertsController');
    $this->resource('submit-information', 'SubmitInformationController');
    $this->resource('primary-committee-meeting', 'PrimaryCommitteeMeetingController');
    $this->resource('list-violations-school', 'ListViolationsSchoolController');
    $this->resource('announcing', 'AnnouncingController');
    $this->resource('display-vote', 'DisplayVoteController');
    $this->resource('announcing-supervisory-vote', 'AnnouncingSupervisoryVoteController');
    $this->resource('supervisory-board-vote', 'SupervisoryBoardVoteController');
    $this->resource('defense', 'DefenseController');
    $this->resource('votiing-supervisory-board', 'VotiingSupervisoryBoardController');
    $this->get('dashboard', 'DashboardController');
});
```

Comment: I am sure you just don't want `$this->get('dashboard', 'DashboardController');`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because it is invalid. As you're using `GET` route, you must specify method name(unless you used `::resource`):

```
$this->get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@methodName');
```

Comment: may be also `$this->resource('dashboard', 'DashboardController');`

Comment: yup, either way

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi : what you are saying is not clear ?

Comment: Yes, that why it throws you an error because `::get()` expect method/action name, but you specify none. Try adding some name like i did and see how it goes

Comment: Change `::get()` to `::resource` if you dont want to specify the action/method

Comment: Only I have a question .

Comment: What about invocable classes. They have only __invoke() and that's what should be used. Is there a proper syntax for that in Laravel Route::*?

Comment: @przemo_li with ```__invoke function()``` in your controller. So in your route you can simple do ```Route::get('someUrl', 'YOurController');```

Answer (score 10):

If you are using laravel 8 you need to add your controller and method name inside the array, otherwise, it will throw an error.

```
Route::get('/projects', User\ProjectController::class, 'index')->name('user.projects');
```

TO

```
 Route::get('/projects', [User\ProjectController::class, 'index'])->name('user.projects');
```

Answer (score 4):

I also face a similar problem:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'Frontend\FrontendController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/post', 'Frontend\FrontendController@post')->name('post');
Route::get('/contact', 'Frontend\FrontendController@contact')->name('contact_us');
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {

    Route::get('/create', 'Backend\BackendController@index');

    //User Route

    Route::get('/registration', '');
});
```

And I just remove the `Route::get('/registration', '');` and it's work for me :)

Answer (score 4):

try removes route cache file by

> php artisan route:clear

Answer (score 3):

Those who are new to Laravel or learning use

```
Route::resource('resource_name','controller_name')
```

to avoid this kind of error when you type:

```
php artisan route:list
```

In cmd or any other command line.

Comment: php artisan route:list helped me to find the bug. thanks

Answer (score 3):

i think its because of :: before the class name instead use @
Route::get('/about','App\Http\Controllers\DemoController::about'); (Not working gives an error)

Route::get('/about','App\Http\Controllers\DemoController@about'); (But this statement works)

Answer (score 3):

For recent versions of laravel, try adding square brackets like

```
Route::post('login',[AuthController::class,'login'])
```

instead of

```
Route::post('login', AuthController::class,'login']).
```

The second route will throw the error `Invalid route action:` since you are not invoking the route. Another alternative you can add an `__invoke` function on your controller if you are using the second route as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

I hit the same issue but with a different cause. So I'm documenting here just in case someone else hits the same cause.

Specifically if you are using a Single Action Controller (ie: with `__invoke`), if you haven't added or omitted the correct `use` Laravel will hide the missing controller with "Invalid route action: [XController]."

**This will fail**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::post('/order', XController::class);
```

**This will pass**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\XController;

Route::post('/order', XController::class);
```

I think its a bit unfortunate that Laravel masks the underlying issue, but I think it only applies to invokable controllers, even though its a silly mistake on my behalf.

Answer (score 2):

Lastly if you set the route like below:

```php
Route::post('example', PostController::class);
```

You should have an `__invoke` method in your controller.